# Open problems concerning Araujo's biseparating maps

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, open-problems

[Araujo](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0001870803002871/1-s2.0-S0001870803002871-main.pdf?_tid=e690026e-1447-11e8-bf32-00000aacb360&acdnat=1518916156_1024c16fb9709444e47c839be4337bc8) stated the following four open questions at the end of his paper, page $518$ and $519.$

> **Question $1:$** Assume that there exists a biseparating map $T:A^n(\Omega:E)\to A^m(\Omega',F)$ which is not linear. 
>   Can we deduce that the support map $h:\Omega'\to\Omega$ is a diffeomorphism of class $n?$
>
> **Problem $2:$** Suppose that $C^\infty(\Omega,E)$ is the space of $E$-valued functions which are of class $C^\infty$ in $\Omega,$ and that $C^\infty(\Omega',F)$ is defined in a similar way.
>   Describe the linear biseparating maps from $C^\infty(\Omega,E)$ onto $C^\infty(\Omega',F).$
>   Must such map be continuous?
>
> **Problem $3:$** Let $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ be unbounded open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^p$ and $\mathbb{R}^q$ respectively. 
>   Describe the linear biseparating maps from $C^n_*(\Omega,E)$ onto $C^m_*(\Omega',F).$
>
> **Problem $4:$** Determine all subspaces $A(\Omega,E)\subseteq A^n(\Omega,E)$ and $B(\Omega',F)\subseteq A^m(\Omega',F)$ such that the existence of a linear biseparating map from $A(\Omega,E)$ onto $B(\Omega',F)$ implies that $E$ and $F$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces.

What is the status of these questions? Any progress on each of them? If yes, any reference is appreciated.

..........................................................................................................................................................

**Definitions:** Let $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^p$ be an open subset and $E$ be a Banach space. 
Denote $C^n(\Omega,E)$ the space of $E$-valued functions $f$ on $\Omega$ that are of class $C^n.$
$T:C^n(\Omega,E)\to C^m(\Omega',F)$ is called biseparating map if $T$ is bijective and 
$$\|Tf\| \|Tg\|=0 \text{ if and only if }\|f\|\|\|g\|=0$$

Comment: Please spell the author's name correctly.